# how to add product to cart in magento 2 using custom controller?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, addtocart

I have tried the following controller file to add product to cart in my custom extension.

```
<?php

namespace MS\Recommendeditems\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $productRepository;

    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
        ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $options = $params['options'];
        $superAttribute = $params['super_attribute'];
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($params['product']);
        $paramater = array('product' => $params['product'],
                          'qty' => $params['qty'],
                          'options' => $options,
                          'super_attribute' => $superAttribute
                ); 
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $request);
        $this->cart->save();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();             
    }
}
```

but this code is not working and it shows the blank page.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214438/magento-2-add-a-product-to-the-cart-programmatically

Comment: check var/log file for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try full of code and add this code in your controller

```
<?php
namespace MS\Recommendeditems\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        Product $product) {
            $this->formKey = $formKey;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->product = $product;      
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
     { 
        $productId =$yourproductid; //yourproduct id like 2
        $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, 
                    'qty'   =>1
                );              
        $product = $this->product->load($productId);       
        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        $this->cart->save();
     }
}
```

And this then check more information :-

**https://meetanshi.com/blog/programmatically-add-product-to-cart-in-magento-2/**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: your code is working but I need to work it with my code.
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest First check check var/log file for errors.
So you will get idea what is wrong with your current code
If still unable to solve then try below code :-

```
protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;      
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
 { 
  $productId =10;
  $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product                
            );              
    //Load the product based on productID   
    $_product = $this->product->load($productId);       
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
 }
```

Comment: I have already checked the var/log files but there is no errors for it.